# socket.io how to upload and send a image to the server?

Tags: node.js, file-upload, socket.io

I have an input that lets a user upload a image, how can i go about getting this image sent to the server?

This is what i have so far:

server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const app = express();
const http = require("http").Server(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(http);

var PORT = 7778;
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname)));
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "index.html"));
});
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    socket.on("send-img", () => {
        console.log("img recieved");
    });
});
http.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log("Server started on port: " + PORT);
});
```

client.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Works!</h1>
        <input type="file" accept=".jpg, jpeg, png" multiple id="img-uplaod" />
        <button id="img-submit">Click Me</button>
    </body>
    <script>
        const socket = io();
        document.getElementById("img-submit").onclick = function () {
            socket.emit("send-img");
        };
    </script>
</html>
```

the answer posted below almost works,but i am getting this error:

```
   at Object.openSync (fs.js:443:3)
    at Object.writeFileSync (fs.js:1194:35)
    at Socket.socket.on (/home/pyroot/Desktop/main-dev/projects-main/sell-anything/server.js:19:6)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at /home/pyroot/Desktop/main-dev/projects-main/sell-anything/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:528:12
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing that you have to do is serializing the image. It means that we need to convert our image file into something that can be transferred through the internet, in this case, the best available option is `base64` encoding. Here is your solution:

### Client-side

```
<script>
    const socket = io();
    document.getElementById("img-submit").onclick = function () {
        const ourFile = document.getElementById('img-uplaod').files[0];
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function() {
             socket.emit("send-img", reader.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(ourFile);
    };
</script>
```

### Server-side

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const app = express();
const http = require("http").Server(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(http);

var PORT = 7778;
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname)));
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "index.html"));
});
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    socket.on("send-img", (image) => {
        const splitted = image.split(';base64,');
        const format = splitted[0].split('/')[1];
        fs.writeFileSync('./image.' + format, splitted[1], { encoding: 'base64' });
    });
});
http.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log("Server started on port: " + PORT);
});
```

Comment: thank you! this almost works, but i get the following error when i writefilesync. I attached it to my post.

Comment: EDIT nevermind figured it out :) thank you for the answer!