# Server is receiving an empty array when emitting a file from the client

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I'm having an issue with emitting an uploaded file, in this case a jpg. When the server side receives the payload from the client, the file itself, when I run it in a console.log server side, is just a {}. Everything else in the payload looks correct.

My code is rather long and I wouldn't want someone to scan through all of it, but essentially I have a file upload button on a webpage which calls a handler like so:

```
<input type="file" style="width:150px;" id="mapUpload" onchange="parent.uploadFileRequest(this, 'map')">
```

it's parent.upload because this html lives inside an iframe, and the js is outside. The handler itself looks sort of like this:

```
function uploadFileRequest(){
    console.log(arguments[0].files[0]);
    socket.emit('uploadFile', arguments[0].files[0]);
}
```

I'm using arguments as I have one handler for uploading files, and the number of arguments varies depending on where it is called from. The console.log there has been returning what I expect,

```
File { name: "testImage.jpg", lastModified: 1690232590473, webkitRelativePath: "", size: 47908, type: "image/jpeg" }
```

On the server side, I have been using the following as a quick debug:

```
socket.on('uploadFile', (file) => {
    console.log(file);
});
```

which is showing as {}. Lastly, I found the following how-to on socket.io website, which seems to suggest this is possible, but for some reason I can't make mine work. https://socket.io/how-to/upload-a-file

Comment: You're calling `uploadFileRequest()` with 2 arguments, but there are no parameters in the function.

Comment: @Barmar `arguments` is a built-in, right?  Doesn't need to be in the signature?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Comment: Completely forgot about that. But why not use normal parameters?

Comment: And why doesn't it use `arguments[1]`?

Comment: Yes, arguments is built in. I was trying to not bombard with a lot of unnecessary code to my question, so I slimmed it down. The call to the handler has a different number of arguments based on where it is called from, hence using arguments. Another callout might have 3 versus 2.

Comment: I suspect your image isn't correctly serialized, so that's why you're seeing an empty object on the receiving end.  The docs you linked seem a bit short on details, and are possibly skipping this key step. Maybe this SO answer would help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67053244/3084820

Comment: Yeah, I've tried what is linked there, reading the file with a FileReader and emitting the result, and that does work, but what I would really like to do is send the file directly, which I'm pretty sure can be done. If I can't figure it out I might end up just doing some more processing on it later, but it seems rather inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with it for a little while, I decided to go back to reading the file and sending the base64 encoded string.

I wanted to avoid having to convert it back to a file or blob to draw it into a canvas, but I added a little function to do that on the  client side after the server broadcasts it to the other clients.

```
getBlob(mapImageFile).then((mapBlob) => {
    let smallImg = new Image();
    smallImg.src = URL.createObjectURL(mapBlob);
    console.log(smallImg.src);
    smallImg.onload = function(){
        let canvas = insideView.document.getElementById(canvasId);
        let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.drawImage(smallImg, 0, 0, 50, 50);
    }
});
  
async function getBlob(base64Image){
    let response = await fetch(base64Image);
    let imgBlob = await response.blob();
    return imgBlob;
}
```

insideView is a reference to the iframe's contentWindow, if anyone was curious, and the canvasId is generated with the canvas a ways above the getBlob call. Essentially, one user uploads an image, and this posts it into a small canvas in other clients' views.